# Contact Form Magento2: move success message to form

Tags: contact-us, contact-form

How to move success (not error) message into contact form?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

hello dear I will implement your functionality in my project. please check the below code with the screenshot.

Please go to your theme directory

app/design/frontend/Magento/customtheme/Magento_Contact/layout/contact_index_index.xml

1. The above path "customtheme" is my theme name so please go to your theme. after in theme created a new folder "Magento_Contact"
2. this Magento_Contact folder created a new folder "layout" and in this folder created a new file contact_index_index.xml

Please add below code your new file contact_index_index.xml

this XML file in the body section adds the below code.

```
 <move element="page.messages" destination="page.wrapper" before="footer-container" />
```

[image]

[image]

I hope this solution works. so please accept my answer and give an upvote.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work for me :(

Comment: ok means you want only the error message shown on the above footer and success message shown on the columns' top.?

Comment: I want to show success and error messages under the button submit which is into contact form. For now all messages are showed on the top of the page as you can see in my example

Comment: ok I understand you can go with the jQuery only contact page.

Comment: because I will share the code for this work for div. container wise. not any particular div add you want to. so, please you may go with jQuery.